# Internal page redirection in Symfony/Sonata

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to work on my sonata sandbox.

The problem that I face this message `internal page redirection` when I try to reload profile or register routes.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @safe.
The easier you make for us to help you the higher your chance of getting an answer. Include some code snippet, error stack trace for example.

Comment: If you've already found a solution why do you haven't post it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this bundle has been updated, there is now a parameter you can set to skip this or not:

`sonata.page.skip_redirection: true`

Answer (score 1):

The internal page redirect is only shown for admins.

If you want to remove it go to

```
PageBundle/Listner/ResponseListener.php
```

And remove this

```
// display a validation page before redirecting, so the editor can edit the current page
        if ($page && $response->isRedirection() && $this->cmsSelector->isEditor() && !$request->get('_sonata_page_skip')) {
            $response = new Response($this->templating->render('SonataPageBundle:Page:redirect.html.twig', array(
                'response'   => $response,
                'page'       => $page,
            )));

            $response->setPrivate();

            $event->setResponse($response);

            return;
        }
```

Comment: Should the `Listner` directory be `Listener`?

Comment: You should never override anything in vendor catalogue (nor any other dependencies your project might have). This is also true for frontend, Wordpress themes and plugins and for any programming language out there.